# LINQ - GroupBy Item and filter based on two Properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items

```
var itema = new ObjX { Id = 1, MajorV = 1, MinorV = 1 };
var itemb = new ObjX { Id = 1, MajorV = 2, MinorV = 1 };
var itemc = new ObjX { Id = 1, MajorV = 3, MinorV = 0 };
var iteme = new ObjX { Id = 2, MajorV = 2, MinorV = 0 };
var itemf = new ObjX { Id = 2, MajorV = 2, MinorV = 1 };
```

And I want to create a linq query to return a list of unique `ids` which have the highest `MajorV` first and then the highest `MinorV` second

With this example the items to be returned are `itemc` and `itemf`.

I have a query of below, but does not take into account the `MinorV`

```
var filteredquery = query.GroupBy(cm => new { cm.Id })
                    .Select(grp => grp.Aggregate((max, cur) =>
                    (max == null || cur.MajorV > max.MajorV) ? cur : max));
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: what expected output for your sample?

Comment: Now the correct results are returned... i'm pretty sure when i tested it before itemc and iteme(instead of itemf) was returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Dmitry Bychenko answer & Stefan Steinegger comment this query is the simplest and works:

```
       var filteredquery = query
                           .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                           .Select(chunk => chunk
                               .OrderByDescending(item => item.MajorV)
                               .ThenByDescending(item => item.MinorV)
                               .First())
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredquery = query.GroupBy(cm => cm.Id)
                .Select(gcm => gcm.OrderByDescending(cm => cm.MajorV).OrderByDescending(cm => cm.MinorV).First());
```

Comment: As "query" seems intermediate list, so I just skip .ToList().

Comment: I see, ThenByDescending(cm => cm.MinorV), typos, forget it.

Answer (score 0):

This is giving me the result you expect:-

```
var result = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                  .Select(x => 
                  {
                     var CriteriaObj = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.MajorV)
                                        .ThenByDescending(z => z.MinorV).First();
                     return new ObjX
                            {
                                Id = x.Key,
                                MajorV = CriteriaObj.MajorV,
                                MinorV = CriteriaObj.MinorV
                            };
                  }).ToList();
```

[**Working Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CgeNsQ)

Comment: This works, but new is not needed see my answer above.

Comment: Yes in your query, you are directly selecting from the list and in my case I am storing the object in a variable and then fetching the values, both will result in correct results.